# Adicionar scroll em janela

Tags: java, eclipse, window-builder

Criei uma janela que ficou com Largura 360 x Altura 800. Só que 800 de altura não dá para ser visto no monitor.

Como faço para adicionar um *scroll* na janela?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Faça um `JPanel` com rolagem usando `JSCrollPane` desta forma:

```
JPanel container = new JPanel();
JScrollPane scrPane = new JScrollPane(container);
add(scrPane);
```

Detalhes

- [How to Use Scroll Panes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html)

Comment: @diegofm porque você não adiciona a resposta?  Não entendi.

Comment: ScrollPane mesmo. Resolvido Obrigado!!

Comment: @Júnior Precisar, corre aqui que ajudaremos como podemos. abraços.

Comment: @diegofm Entendi! Você sinalizou como ampla?!